# Unordered_map of unordered_map vs custom hash function for pair key C++?

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I have some keys that are `pair<string, string>`. I was originally going to write my own hash function but thought that it might be easier to just implement an `unordered_map<string, unordered_map<string, val>>`. Are there any performance differences between these two I should be aware of?

Comment: standard libraries implementation will probably be more optimized for speed, so I think using unordered_map is better

Comment: Consider absl::flat_hash_map from abseil if you can pull in a dependency. Better than std::unordered_map in many ways, and supports pair keys out of the box.

Comment: I would go with a custom template pair hash function. So it can be useful with any `std::pair<T,T>` type. Qt already has it: [source code](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/include/qt/QtCore/qhashfunctions.h.html#_Z5qHashRKSt4pairIT_T0_Ej). And `boost::hash_combine` might be interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `std::unordered_map<std::pair<std::string, std::string>, Value, [pair_hash][1]>` for two reasons:

1. Performance

Of course, you can measure your two versions with your favorite profiler, but basing on my experience - the number of allocation is what matters here the most - so see:

`flat_map.insert(key, value));` will create on average just one new bucket (or extend one), whilst

```
auto it = map2.insert(make_pair(key.first, map1{}));
it->second.insert(make_pair(key.second, value));
```

have to create empty map1 - what might not be zero-cost. Then it has to add/extend two buckets (list associated with the given hash value).

2. Maintainability/Readability

The Second reason is more important for me. Flat(one) map is easy to use. You could see in insert example already that it is more complicated, but consider erase - it is so complicated, that it is easy to make a mistake:

```
void remove(
   std::unordered_map<std::string, 
           std::unordered_map<std::string, Value>>& map,
    std::pair<std::string, std::string> const& key)
{
   auto it1 = map.find(key.first);
   if (it1 == map.end()) return;
   it1->second.erase(key.second);
   // easy to forget part
   if (it1->second.empty())
   {
       map.erase(it1);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Defining a simple hash function in your case is trivial and performant. If the `std::pair` is semantically the key, then this approach makes your intent clear. It also allows duplicates of the first member of the `std::pair` in your map, as you only need the entire key to be unique. In terms of usage, you also avoid the additional layer of indirection, with nested maps.

Example implementation:

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:49,endLineNumber:28,positionColumn:49,positionLineNumber:28,selectionStartColumn:49,selectionStartLineNumber:28,startColumn:49,startLineNumber:28),source:%27%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Cfunctional%3E%0A%23include+%3Cutility%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstring%3E%0A%23include+%3Cunordered_map%3E%0A%0Ausing+pairSS+%3D+std::pair%3Cstd::string,+std::string%3E%3B%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T%3E%0Astruct+PairHash+%7B%7D%3B%0A%0Atemplate%3C%3E+struct+PairHash%3CpairSS%3E%0A%7B%0A++++std::size_t+operator()(pairSS+const%26+pair)+const+noexcept%0A++++%7B%0A++++++++return+std::hash%3Cstd::string%3E%7B%7D(pair.first)+%5E%0A++++++++++++++(std::hash%3Cstd::string%3E%7B%7D(pair.second)+%3C%3C+1)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++std::pair+myPair+%3D+%7B%22Hi%22,+%22bye%22%7D%3B%0A%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+PairHash%3CpairSS%3E%7B%7D(myPair)+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B%0A%0A++++struct+val%7B%7D%3B%0A++++std::unordered_map%3CpairSS,+val,+PairHash%3CpairSS%3E%3E+hashMap%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:45.28727612542895,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g102,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%270%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B17%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+10.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:35.620151213375685,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%231+with+x86-64+gcc+10.2%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:54.71272387457105,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```
...

using pairSS = std::pair<std::string, std::string>;

namespace std
{
    template<> struct hash<pairSS>
    {
        std::size_t operator()(pairSS const& pair) const noexcept
        {
            return std::hash<std::string>{}(pair.first) ^
                (std::hash<std::string>{}(pair.second) << 1);
        }
    };
}

int main()
{
    std::pair myPair = {"Hi", "bye"};

    std::cout << std::hash<pairSS>{}(myPair) << std::endl;

    struct val{};
    std::unordered_map<pairSS, val> hashMap;
}
```